# Improving Python user defined max function

Tags: python, performance, max

I am new to programming and am trying to understand how to "think" more programmatically in Python. I wrote a function that returns the largest element in an array without using max:

```
def max_userdefined(array):
    """
    Finds largest value of nonempty array of numbers in O(n)
    :param: list/tuple of values
    :return: max value
    """
    try:
        assert isinstance(array, list or tuple)
        result = array[0]
        for element in array:
            if element > result:
                result = element
        return result
    except IndexError:
        return 'Please pass in a nonempty array'
    except AssertionError:
        return 'Please pass in a list or tuple'
    except TypeError:
        return 'Please make sure elements of array are all floats or ints'
```

How can I improve the above code? Open to any criticism or if anyone can recommend a good Pythonic style guide.

Comment: this question may be better suited here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yep, codereview. Also `isinstance(array, list or tuple)` is invalid - use `isinstance(array, (list, tuple))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def max_userdefined(array):
    myMax = l[0]
    for num in l:
        if myMax < num:
            myMax = num
    return myMax


print max_userdefined ([1,2,3,4,5])
```

**Output**

```
5
```

Or You can do something like following by using sorted.

```
def max_userdefined(array):
    return sorted(array)[-1]
```

Comment: What is the runtime of Python's built-in sorted method? Is it O(n log n)? If so, wouldn't that be slower than the forloop way?

Comment: You can use any one way from above. It is just for your reference. As well you can try it both to identify How much time it will take for execution?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def umax(array):
    global biggest
    for num in array:
        if num > biggest:
            biggest = num


>>> biggest = int()
>>> nums = (1, 9, 6, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 0)
>>> umax(nums)
>>> biggest
9
```

Comment: @Jignesh Jarsaniya OK you were first.

Answer (score 0):

For returning the greatest number from a list the simple algorithm followed is compare two numbers and keep the larger number in a variable, then print the variable OR you can use python shortcut using sort.

1. Using user defined function:

   ```
   def greatest_ele_list(listobj):
       greatest=listobj[0]    
       for i in range(len(listobj)):
           if listobj[i]>greatest:
              greatest=listobj[i]
           else:
              pass
       return greatest
   print greatest_ele_list([4,5,3,8,1])
   ```
2. Using sort:

   ```
   def greatest_ele_list(listobj):
       listobj2=listobj.sort()
       return listobj2[-1]
   print greatest_ele_list([4,5,3,8,1])
   ```

   Output:  `>>> 8`